# CSS: Create looking down *D Shaped* div

Tags: css, clip-path

I have tried my best to use clipPath editors but not able to achieve a shape like this one.
Any help ?

[image]

Comment: What's the problem with what you've got?

Comment: @DavidThomas All I'm able to achieve is a half-circled div with *ellipse* like this : `clip-path: ellipse(50% 50% at 50% 0%);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
.dshape {
  /* to ensure the starting shape is a square,
     with the inline and block sizing in a
     ratio of 1 to 1: */
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  /* in Latin (left-to-right) languages this
     is equivalent to 'width' ('block-size'
     would be the equivalent of 'height'): */
  inline-size: 10em;
  background-color: red;
  /* using a circular clip path of 80% of
     the element's size, with the clipping
     circle centred at 50% on the inline
     axis, and zero on the block-axis: */
  clip-path: circle(80% at 50% 0);
}
```

```html
<div class="dshape"></div>
```

Comment: Now this looks exactly like the one I wanted.
Will just tweak the dimensions a bit and I'm good.
Thanks @David Thomas

Comment: You're very welcome, I'm glad to have helped :)

Answer (score 0):

is this what you want?

creating a `div` with `200px/200px` Adding border-radius bottom right and bottom left `border-radius: 0 0 100% 100%;`

```css
.dshape {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 0 0 100% 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="dshape"></div>
```

Comment: using border-radius can only make it look either to the left or right, but not to the bottom, which is what I want. I thought clip-path was the solution @UmairFarooq

Comment: no you can make it to bottom as well.i will change the answer check now

Comment: you just have to change where to add border-raduis.`border-radius: 0 0 100% 100%;` 
0 top-left, 0 top-right,100% bottom-right,100% bottom-left. shortcut works as clockwise

Comment: Damn that actually worked
 I never considered that.

Thanks @UmairFarooq.

Comment: It's close to the one I wanted.
It's rather perfectly rounded on the points of contact between the circle and the rectangle.
So I'll go with the answer below but thanks for the help though

Comment: sure its okay..